# getting profile data from auth0 hooks into nextjs getInitialProps or getServerSideProps

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks, next.js, auth0

I want to load data form an Auth0 useUser hook, which can only be called from a page functional component.

that's fine but when i return jsx, the hook call is async. and the data is not available to be used when the jsx component is rendered (ie return <Home user={data} /> the data is from a hook call and Home renders before data is available) and data is only available after Home is rendered.

Please is there a better approach to achieve this?

I want data from hooks to be available during rendering of a page.

```
import getUser from './api/hooks/user';
import Homepage from './home';

function Controller ({userAuth}) {
//2. it is only acceptable to be called here
//let user = getUser();

    return <Homepage user={userAuth} />

}

Controller.getInitialProps = async (context) =\> {
//1. this is wrong cause nextjs disallows it
let user = getUser();

//3. but the getInitialProps, getStaticProps and getServerSideProps passes data to the page component as       //props and renders the page only when data is available.

return{userAuth: user}
}

export default Controller;
```

```
//4. Also I Used
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

Controller.getInitialProps = async (context) =\> {
//5. the user object from getUser Hook is present there.
let user = getSession();

//6. but sometimes user.user returns undefined

return{userAuth: user.user}
}
```

Comment: Use `getServerSideProps` then call `const session = getSession(req, res);` to retrieve the user's session. You can destructure `req` and `res` from context, e.g. `const { req, res } = context;`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that I actually used `const session = getSession(context.req, context.res);`,

the problem there is that session.user that's available in the session object when i `console.log(session)` sometimes returns undefined.